# What is the preferred way to return error?

Tags: c, error-handling, api-design

I'm stuck with providing error handling facility for functions from my library's public API. For example I have some `data_source` and a `queue` and the function is `get_data` currently looks as:

```
typedef struct data_source data_source;

typedef struct queue queue;

/**
 * Returns:
 *  0 - on success
 * -1 - on data source failure
 * -2 - on queue overflow
 */
int get_data(data_source *ds, queue *queue);
```

But looking at the `POSIX`'s errno approach they use the return type to indicate that some error occurred and `errno` to set the error code. I'm not sure if using the `errno` for my library API is a good choice, but taking the idea into account I would design the function as follows:

```
/**
 * Returns:
 *  0 - on success
 * -1 - on error and error_code is set to
 *      1 - if queue overflow occurs
 *      2 - if data source failure detected
 */
int get_data(data_source *ds, queue *queue, int *error_code);
```

Is the second example sort of (common | more preferred then the first one) C approach for error handling?

Comment: Is there a reason why simply throwing an exception is not feasible?

Comment: The out parameter, `error_code`, is a good method to return an error imho. For instance look at how Windows COM [implements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/structure-of-com-error-codes) error handling. That way your function signature is not coupled to error handling at all. You could conveniently return values at your whim, but still implement an error checking mechanism.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's what I'm asking. In the first example I used the return value, but in `libc` functions have return type `int`  which is either `-1` or `0` and the error code is set into `errno`. So I thought that it is more common to use out parameter for error code.

Comment: The second one would be a more consistent interface, since the return value might already be giving multiple values from different functions in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

errno is a macro in errno.h.

Think of it as an external int that the system or libs might set to something. I.e. it's not a argument to your lib's function but a global int.

If you want to use return values as error codes or use errno is entirely up to you.